# Export issues in ArcGIS 10.0

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, export, file-formats

I'm working on a bigger map for panaflex, 12'*10'. Since basemaps in ArcGIS cannot b exported as vectors (or may be I don't know how), I have to export a jpeg file or a pdf etc (pdf, even, without basemap has stripes of image). I have tried to export the file and I rec this error: "Invalid image parameter has been specified while rendering/writing the image". File gets exported in ai format but does not open in coral or adobe.

I would like to receive suggestions on how can I export this image to the best of quality with smaller size so that my designer may not have to work on this as exported map tends to be of huge size.

I do not receive any errors on page size A4 or A3 etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're getting these errors, because the map is just too big to process. I can imagine that the size of the exported file is a couple of gigs.

You need to ask yourself a few things.

- Does your designer need a basemap or can he be satisfied without? With other words: is the basemap essential for the final product or is more a guideline for your designer?
- You can let the designer download a basemap, so you won't have to export it from ArcMap. The results are the same, because he is editing the map anyway.
- Tweaking your export settings will help reduce the filesize and processing time enormously

Good luck

Comment: Thank you Stefan but unfortunately this ain't the case here. yes the file size gets big as1 gb or so which I observed in previous times. this one just not getting exported & I have no idea why. Map designing is all mine n designer would just add other stuff n place it along.

Comment: I see. My suggestion still would be to alter your export settings. My experience with exporting maps from ArcMap is that large maps always give problems.

You also can try to export the map with ArcPy. It doens't use the ArcMap UI so it doesn't need the resources for it. 

If that doesn't work you need to check the changes you've made to your map.

Comment: yes I could work on ArcPy but I'm not a programing guy n never used that. For now I used lesser DPIs for resolution and after hours I could finally get an export. Hopefully I'll work with it.

Comment: Good luck with it

Comment: So kind of you... :)

Comment: Can you please flag it as answer? Thanks  :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33360/discussion-between-adel-and-stefan).

Answer (score 2):

I've done a few maps that are 10x12' but my approach was to export 8 maps with cut marks then after plotting i glued them together.

First of all, forget PDF export out of GIS for anything but simple vector maps. Any transparency or raster will rasterize anything bellow that particular layer and the size is simply enormous.  Exporting complex maps containing many layers, annotation classes, rasters and transparent layers has ALWAYS been problematic in ArcGIS and it has never been resolved. One approach that always works for me is to export to a TIFF @ 300DPI or more then convert that tiff to PDF using Acrobat. Acrobat renderrer works amazingly well with lossless tiff (not so well with lossy files such as jpeg). Initially, the Tiff will be huge but acrobat down-samples it to a great quality image pdf that is also small in file size.

Back to the 10x12' map - I basically digitized 8 rectangles for the 8 extents to be assembled together with a little bit of overlap, then added some lines and tics for cut marks and then using data drive pages created a single map document for the whole job. This way I could still place all my annotations in single document and export all final maps from the same document. (as tiff then used acrobat to convert to PDF)

Comment: thank you for the nice piece of info. Data driven pages is a new thing for me. But does it work for tiff too, I mean I made pages, tried your technique for rectangular polygons and export to single file worked for pdf only and when the export was complete (in good lesser time) pdf did not open as it said "out of memory"... export to tiff does not allow features that it allows for pdf export.